# How to make a status by comparing the dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server 2005

Leave Table

```
ID StartDate EndDate 

001 04/01/2010 04/02/2010
002 04/02/2010 04/03/2010
…
```

Event Table

```
ID Date PresentDate Status

001 03/30/2010 03/30/2010 Present
001 03/31/2010 null       absent
001 04/01/2010 null       Leave
001 04/02/2010 null       Leave
001 04/03/2010 null       absent
001 04/04/2010 04/04/2010 Present
….
```

All the Datecolumn datatype is datetime

In the Status Column, if Present Date is null then it will display as “absent”, if not null then it will display as “present”.  Now if we apply a leave for the date then it will display as “Leave” in status column.

Query

```
Select 
    id, date, present date
    , CASE WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN t1.Status ELSE ‘Leave’ END AS status 
from event table as t1 
left outer join leave table as t2 on 
    t1.id = t2.id and t1.date between t2.startdate and t2.enddate
```

The above method is working, but I need to add one more condition.

Once if we applied the leave for the particular employee in the Leave Table then it should compare the Present Date column, if Present Date Column is empty then it should display as “leave”

Expected Output

```
ID Date PresentDate Status

001 03/30/2010 03/30/2010 Present
001 03/31/2010 null       absent
001 04/01/2010 null       Leave
001 04/02/2010 null       Leave
001 04/03/2010 null       Leave (Expect this value)
001 04/04/2010 04/04/2010 Present
….
```

From the above output Leave is starting from 04/01/2010 to 04/02/2010, then next column of present date is null then status should display as a “Leave”, once present date is not null then it should display as “Present.

Method

```
We can display as "Leave" in status column from Start Date to end date of leave table, after that leave date end then we can compare with PresentDate column, if PresentDate column is null then it should display as "Leave", once data is available in present column then status should display with normal condition.
```

How to make a query for the above condition.

Need Query Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select E.id, E.date, E.presentdate, *,
    case
    when E.presentdate is not null then 'Present'
    when E2.presentdate is not null then 'Absent'
    when L.ID is not null then 'Leave'
    else 'Absent'
    end
from Event E
outer apply (
    select top 1 *
    from Leave L
    where E.presentdate is null and E.date >= L.startdate
      AND e.ID = L.ID
    order by L.startDate desc) L
outer apply (
    select top 1 *
    from Event E2
    where E.presentdate is null
      and E2.presentdate is not null
      and E.date >= E2.date and E2.date > L.startdate      
      AND e2.ID = e.ID
    order by E2.presentdate desc) E2
order by E.date
```

Leave table

```
ID          StartDate               EndDate
----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1           2010-04-01 00:00:00.000 2010-04-02 00:00:00.000
1           2010-04-02 00:00:00.000 2010-04-03 00:00:00.000
1           2010-04-05 00:00:00.000 2010-04-05 00:00:00.000
```

Output

```
id          date                    presentdate             
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -------
1           2010-03-30 00:00:00.000 2010-03-30 00:00:00.000 Present
1           2010-03-31 00:00:00.000 NULL                    Absent
1           2010-04-01 00:00:00.000 NULL                    Leave
1           2010-04-02 00:00:00.000 NULL                    Leave
1           2010-04-03 00:00:00.000 NULL                    Leave -**
1           2010-04-04 00:00:00.000 2010-04-04 00:00:00.000 Present
1           2010-04-05 00:00:00.000 NULL                    Leave
1           2010-04-06 00:00:00.000 NULL                    Leave -**
1           2010-04-07 00:00:00.000 NULL                    Leave -**
1           2010-04-08 00:00:00.000 2010-04-08 00:00:00.000 Present
1           2010-04-09 00:00:00.000 NULL                    Absent
1           2010-04-10 00:00:00.000 NULL                    Absent
1           2010-04-11 00:00:00.000 2010-04-11 00:00:00.000 Present
```

The ones marked -** are not covered by Leave records, but they show leave because they follow a Leave period, correct? `2010-04-09` for example remains "Absent" because it follows a Present record (without actually being present).

Comment: I have n numbers of empid, and your query also not compared the event table empid = leave table empid, it is comparing only the dates.

Comment: @Richard, Thanks for your reply, I tried your query, it is not displaying properly as "leave".  When the leave is started it is displaying as "Leave", after the leave date is end, it is displaying as "Absent" instead of Leave.

Comment: @Richard, Thanks for your response, your query is executing but performance is very slow.  I am getting time out expire problem.

Comment: It showing some duplicates values, when i use the "distinct" then it showing error as "Time Out Expire"

Comment: @Gopal - answer edited again. I have increased the size of my test data and could see the duplicates, which have now been fixed

Comment: Thanks for your answer, after leave end date it is showing absent instead of leave

Comment: Almost your query is working with my logic, could be please recheck

Comment: i applied  leave from 2 feb to 8 feb, your query is showing as 2 feb is leave then from 3 feb onwards it is showing as "Absent"

Comment: @Gopal - please recheck data. See the data above - The leave is for 5-Apr, but the next two days show "Leave" not "Absent"

Comment: Could be please recheck the query again, because when i run the query it is showing 5th date is leave after that it is showing absent until next present date is available

Comment: your query was worked before, only the problem is time out expired, after you changed the query, now time out expire problem was solved, but output is not displaying exactly, could you please check the case condition

Comment: @Gopal I checked it using the same data, and the query posted produces the output as shown.

Comment: @Richard, I applied the leave for the empid 001 from 05 feb to 10 feb, then i used your query for the empid 002 from 01 feb to 15 feb. 05 feb it is showing as leave and 10 feb it is showing as leave for the empid 002, it should show only for empid 001.

Comment: @Gopal next time, please show table structures **and** describe the columns. I had no idea ID is an "employee id".  Updated answer.

Comment: @Richard, Thank you very much, your query is working perfectly.  One more small requirement.  when presentdate is null and day = friday then status should display as friday.

Comment: I Tried like this "CASE WHEN E.PresentDate is null and E.DateName = 'Friday' THEN 'Friday' WHEN E.presentdate IS NOT NULL THEN 'Present' WHEN E2.presentdate IS NOT NULL THEN 'Absent' WHEN L.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Leave' When E.presentdate is ELSE 'Absent' END AS Status"  The Query is not showing the status properly